# JavaScript and the browser's back/forward button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http, browser, cross-browser

I have some JavaScript that shows a notification if there exists a value in ASP.NET's `Session`. It's probably not the best solution which I'm learning now, but here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["Alert"] != null)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", Session["Alert"].ToString());
            Session["Alert"] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

`Session["Alert"]` has the JS function which shows the notification:

```
Session["Alert"] = "showAlert('test')";

function showAlert(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
```

If it's been assigned a value, the code runs successfully and the notification shows. Clicking the browser's back button and then forward button shows the alert again because the page doesn't go through its lifecycle.

How could I prevent the alert from showing more than once? I've tried adding a global JavaScript variable like `var alertShown = false;` and checking that in the `showAlert` function but that doesn't work.

Is there a cross-browser way I could get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters you'd have to avoid the client's navigation cache (often a back/forward doesn't actually pull the page back down).

After that hurdle you can look at (ironically) using a session variable to store if it's been viewed [output] and only dump it to the page once.

if that seems to much, you could just add a cookie check in the function so when it's run (and re-run) it checks for a cookie and, when absent, makes an alert and sets a cookie. Pseudocode:

```
function showAlert(msg){
  if (cookie[msg] == null){ // a cookie doesn't exist for this msg
    alert(msg); // alert the msg
    cookie[msg] = true; // set the cookie so the next pass is ignored
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think cookies is the way to go. I'll look at how to get/set cookies with JS.